# How to get the start time of an SQL process?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, msscc

A job running on our SQL server failed.  We are running MS SQL server 2005.
While investigating, the following question came up: When was this process initiated on the server?  Is there any query I can run that will give me this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE msdb
SELECT * FROM dbo.sysjobs_view

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'dbo.sysjobs_view'.

Comment: Check permissions/server version

Comment: I executed the query and i got the details thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Jim, I'm running as "sa" on SQL Server 2005. However, I just looked at the _FROM_ portion of your answer and took the table name, completely missing the _USE msdb_ so the table did not exist in my current db. I prefer writing the query as __SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view__ and not using a _USE_.  What column contains the "start time of the SQL process"?

Comment: Hi KM,
To be fair I read the question as "When was the job created on the server?" rather than "When did it run?"

Comment: ha, I guess that the OP read it that way too ;-) as you got the "correct answer"!

Answer (score 3):

This should give you what you need

```
SELECT 
    Jobs.name, 
    StartTime = CONVERT 
        ( 
            DATETIME, 
            RTRIM(run_date) 
            ) 
            +  
            ( 
            run_time * 9 
            + run_time % 10000 * 6 
            + run_time % 100 * 10 
        ) / 216e4 
    ,
    endTime = CONVERT 
        ( 
            DATETIME, 
            RTRIM(run_date) 
            ) 
            +  
            ( 
            run_time * 9 
            + run_time % 10000 * 6 
            + run_time % 100 * 10 
            + 25 * run_duration 
        ) / 216e4 
FROM 
    msdb..sysjobhistory JobHistory 
    INNER JOIN msdb..sysjobs Jobs 
        ON Jobs.job_id = JobHistory.job_id 
WHERE 
JobHistory.step_name = '(Job outcome)'
```

Answer (score 0):

using management studios, you can right click the job and click view history.  this will containt the list of executions for the job.

Comment: This job is a continous job and is cycling execution status for every one minute.Thank you very much for the advise.